# smartdiagram 0.2 / xparse / Kubuntu

Tags: installing, texlive, ubuntu, xparse

I have a package dependency problem on Kubuntu 12.10. I have installed Texlive2012 from the known ppa.
The brandnew "smartdiagram 0.2" package has a dependency for xparse. This package does not exist in the ppa. I tried to compile it into my local texmf tree, but it errors out because it does not find "l3docstrip.tex". 
But this "l3docstrip.tex" is already supposed to be there, because it is part of the "l3kernel" package. And this package is already installed from the ppa.
Where do I go from here ? I don't want to mess up the whole installation.

Answer (score 4):

I have been using Ubuntu for quite some time and I started with TeXlive from the PPA just like you but soon realized (thanks to the help of some fellow board members) it was no good. I removed the default TeXlive and switched to the version available on the [TUG](http://www.tug.org/) site and I've been a happy chap ever since. I suggest you do the same. The installation is pretty straightforward, details [here](http://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html).

Comment: The vanilla installation is a test for patience but worth it. Just finished it and it works like a charm. Highly recommended for -all- Ubuntu users.

Comment: @blue_tiger300 I have also been using it on Windows 7, I've had no problems whatsoever so far. Also, can you please accept my answer if you are happy with it. Thank you.